# What is the benefit of separating different classes belonging to the same module in different files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, rubygems, swagger-codegen

I recently used Swagger-Codegen to auto-generate a Ruby gem, and along with generating a file for each individual API endpoint, it also generated dozens of model files for every possible collection of data the API could potentially return.

Both the API methods files as well as the models begin by declaring the same module name `SwaggerClient`, then contain the file's class, which is also the name of the file, except in camel case:

```
module SwaggerClient
  class GetWalletsForbidden
    ...
  end
end
```

As I understand it, you could technically combine all of these into a single file, declaring the the module once at the beginning and placing of the classes inside of it.

When I look at the top-level gem file `swagger_client.rb`, it seems even more strange: line after line of `require`:

```
...
require swagger_client/api/assets.api
require swagger_client/api/bookmarks.api
require swagger_client/api/calendar.api
...
```

I know that, especially when working with Rails, auto-generation is used quite a lot, but this seems excessive to me.

What is the benefit of keeping so many little pieces in separate files? Is it just for the organizational benefits? I know Rails does a lot of complicated things behind-the-scenes... is it related to this? Does it improve performance? Or do I just have the wrong idea of what constitutes "excessive" when it comes to `require`?

Answer (score 0):

Swagger Codegen uses `tags` to classify API endpoints into different files so you can technically put all endpoints into a single file by using the same `tags` in all API operations.

Here is an example of `tags` in the operation: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/modules/swagger-codegen/src/test/resources/2_0/petstore.yaml#L32

However, we would recommend you to leverage `tags` to put API endpoints/operations into different files for organizational benefits, especially for an API with a lot of endpoints (e.g. 500+)